# How do I write an async version of subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, subprocess, python-asyncio

In the new asyncio framework, how do I write a drop-in async equivalent of [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to capture the full output of a process execution?

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem(s) are you having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
async def check_output(*args, **kwargs):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args, 
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        **kwargs,
    )   
    stdout_data, stderr_data = await p.communicate()
    if p.returncode == 0:
        return stdout_data
```

A simple example solution (does not raise an error on failure, but instead returns None)